# get failure reason from AngularJS $http.post catch

Tags: angularjs

I have something like the following:

```
        $http.post('http://some.url/', {service: "/", path: "/"})
        .then(function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          deferred.resolve(result);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
          deferred.reject(error);
        });
```

Inside the catch I am logging the error and get something like the following:

```
{
    config: {
        data: {service: "/", path: "/"},
        headers: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"},
        jsonpCallbackParam: "callback",
        method: "POST",
        paramSerializer: ƒ (e),
        transformRequest: [ƒ],
        transformResponse: [ƒ],
        url: "http://some.url/"
    },
    data: null,
    headers: ƒ (n),
    status: -1,
    statusText: "",
    xhrStatus: "error",
}
```

Is there some way I can get the actual reason for the error (like net::ERR_FAILED or net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED or whatever it happens to be)? The call is failing for some of my users and I don't have enough information to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can't get that information - this failure is caused by the requestError function at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/26a5779cddf70944b7548e3a6410d35237a516e5/src/ng/httpBackend.js, which is assigned to xhr.onerror

xhr.onerror will not give any specific details about what the failure was (Chrome seems to be non-compliant in that it gives onerror one argument of type ProgressEvent but it still has no useful data).